# Why would wireless tethering stop working on two different devices at the same time

Tags: lg, wifi-tethering, verizon

I have an LGVS995S on the left using Tracfone which is probably on Verizon towers and an LGVS986 on the right using Verizon Prepaid which is definitely on Verizon Towers. They both stopped allowing me to wirelessly tether at the same time and give the exact same message. The LGVS986 on the right was allowing me to wifi-tether as recent as yesterday. I hadn't tried with the LGVS995S in about a month, but it's never failed to tether until now.

I just wirelessly tethered my iPhone 11 Pro which is also on Verizon Prepaid without problems.

I would think this must be related to the carrier somehow, but how, why and what can I do?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verizon has disabled hotspot / tethering on LG phones. See the following posts.

https://community.verizon.com/t5/LG/Mobile-hot-spot-problems-LG-V30/m-p/1239650#M9945

https://community.verizon.com/t5/Verizon-Wireless-Services/Hotspot-Suddenly-Not-Working/m-p/1239529#M127081

Comment: Wow. Thank you for answering. I searched and searched and couldn't find anything. What a wicked company Verizon is for this.